# WCF Streaming: Last byte is lost

Tags: wcf, streaming

I have a WCF service which has one method returning a stream.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyMessage Test();
}
```

Now, `MyMessage` is defined like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class MyMessage
{
    public MyMessage(string file)
    {
        this.Stream = File.OpenRead(file);
        this.Length = Stream.Length;
    }

    [MessageHeader]
    public long Length;

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Stream;
}
```

Peachy.

The service has a streamed response, using `basicHttpBinding`. This is the binding configuration:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicStreaming"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferSize="65536" transferMode="StreamedResponse" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Now this is where things start to get *interesting*. When calling this service, **the last byte is lost** if i read the stream in a particular way. Here is the code illustrating the two different approaches:

```
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();

        //this way the last byte is lost
        Stream stream1;
        var length = client.Test(out stream1);
        var buffer1 = new byte[length];
        stream1.Read(buffer1, 0, (int)length);
        File.WriteAllBytes("test1.txt", buffer1);
        stream1.Close();

        //here i receive all bytes
        Stream stream2;
        length = client.Test(out stream2);
        var buffer2 = new byte[length];
        int c = 0, b;
        while ((b = stream2.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            buffer2[c++] = (byte)b;
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes("test2.txt", buffer2);
        stream2.Close();
```

I am sure I'm missing something, but can anyone point out to me exactly why this is happening? The biggest problem is that in another service, whichever way i read the stream, i lose the last byte, but maybe by identifying the problem here I can solve that one too.

**Technical details:**

- IIS 7.0
- .NET 3.5
- Basic HTTP Binding
- Streamed response mode

**Note:** I have uploaded the project isolating the problem, so anyone can try it out: [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/?2rikpd13jj261pp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer as to why this works (my brain isn't fully engaged at the moment), however this DOES work:

```
var buffer1 = new byte[length+2];
stream1.Read(buffer1, 0, buffer1.Length);
```

(and, yes, you end up with a buffer that's too large. It's just a starting point for further thinking)

In testing I found +1 isn't large enough, but +2 is.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried setting the size of the buffer to 13 and read length to 13, but got the same problem as in your example. For some reason it wants a larger buffer.

Comment: Seems a buffer that is two bytes larger than apparently needed, is the key. Your guess as to why is as good as mine.

Comment: Things just get weirder and weirder :) Thanks for the reply, I'd really love to learn why this is happening. Hope someone can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Why passing a count of (length + 1)? It should be length, otherwise you are attempting to read one more byte than what is available.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to edit that, it was just something i tried out. The problem appears when trying with length.